# (Google App Engine) How can I keep my password long time for updating content?

Tags: google-app-engine

Now when I run this command:

/usr/bin/python ~/google_appengine/appcfg.py update ~/cdn

I should write email and password.
And it is keeping some time, but after a day, I should write email and
password again.

How can I keep my auntification (email and password) for long time
(month, year)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour.

The best you can do is to stash your password in some file, and use the --email and --passin command line options, for example:

```
appcfg.py update ~/cdn --email=myemail@gmail.com --passin < /path/to/my/passwd
```

Where passwd is a file that contains only your password.
This way you're just one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-r away from updating your favorite App Engine app.

Comment: Yes. it is working! I've created new email and added it in "Application permissions", for security reason. And now I can keep password in file.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, "for security reason" will not prevent you from somebody controling your app engine application if he gets the password. And once he is in the app engine dashboard, he can just remove all other admins (even the original project creator). I wouldn't trade the "convenience" of entering your password with the dangers associated, at least not if you care about this application.